# Problem with Bootstrap Theme and Jquery Multi

Tags: javascript, theming

I was using the bootstrap theme for drupal and jquery update and everything worked ok. But by client requirements I have to use Jquery Multi instead of Jquery Update and now, this returns two errors:

[image: error capture]

All scripts are loaded right(jQuery.js, jQuery-1.11.2, swicth.js, bootstrap.js)

I'm sure I'm missing something but I have no idea what can be.